# iOS: Using the same UIView for five buttons

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a form with five different `UIbutton` instances. When I push one, I have to show different options, so my problem is, How can I know which button I have pushed using the same `UIView`? I don't want to create five UIViews. Is it possible give an ID to the buttons?

Answer (score 1):

You can assign a tag to each UIButton in this manner :

```
[button setTag:4]
```

or you can set it in Interface Builder in the View attributes of the UIButton.

Then in your IBAction :

```
- (IBAction)message:(id)sender 
{
  int currentSender = [sender tag];
  switch(currentSender) {
  // Different actions
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but there is another problem. Before i had model transiction, so now, how can i pass the variable currentSender to the other view? With the function prepareForSegue?

Answer (score 1):

As @Florent pointed out, you can use a tag. But even this complication is not needed - you can directly compare the button objects themselves.

```
- (void)buttonClicked:(UIButton *)sender
{
    if (sender == button1) {
        // button 1 clicked
    } else if (sender == button2) {
        // etc.
    }
}
```

Comment: I have added a tag in the build interface but i have a problem when i push the button. currentSender int 15479720

Comment: @user669003 that's unfortunate.

Comment: @user669003 (if you told me what the actual problem is, I could help you.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
(IBAction)nextHipoacusia:(id)sender
 { 
  int currentSender = ((UIButton *)sender).tag;
 }
```

Comment: I have the same problem, the program closes when i press the button.

Comment: then you should check your xib, may be there is some error in linking the IBOutlets.
some times we forget to remove the unwanted IBOutlet link from the xib. Just check the xib again for safe side.